# Doxygen C++ - Not documenting virtual functions in a template class

Tags: c++, inheritance, documentation, virtual, doxygen

I have a template class that has a bunch of pure virtual and implemented virtual functions. I then have children inherit from this class. I want to document the functions in the virtual parent class and have children inherit this documentation in Doxygen.

For example (I can't post the real source).

```
template <typename A>
class Parent {
   /** Documentation
    */
   virtual void pure() = 0;

   /** More Docs
    */
   virtual void notpure() {
      ...
   }
};
```

In a different file with all proper includes (at least for the compiler)

```
class Child: public Parent<int> {
   void pure() {
      ...
   }
};
```

I then want Doxygen to generate documentation for both classes with the same documentation for each function unless I re-document the overridden function.

I run Ubuntu 14.04 and use the repository Doxygen 1.8.6 in case it matters.

Thank you

Answer (score 6, accepted):

So, I will answer my own question. Sort of.

If anyone has this same problem, be sure to check for comment bugs. Doxygen handled my templates fine, but I did have a problem because I have the habit of putting /* code /**/ in my programs so I can quickly uncomment large blocks of code quickly while debugging. Doxygen does not like this!.

I had the error message

> File ended in the middle of a comment block! Perhaps a missing \endcode?

It took me a while to wade through the warnings generated because I had several undocumented files. This was taken care of by using

> EXTRACT_ALL = YES

In my config file. [HERE](http://doxygen.10944.n7.nabble.com/Missing-endcode-message-td6597.html) is someone who has a similar problem as I was.

Answer (score 5):

According to the [INHERIT_DOCS](http://www.doxygen.nl/manual/config.html#cfg_inherit_docs) tag, it should already do that if you have it set to '*yes*'.

AFAIK doxygen has had some problems with parsing templates classes and that might be the reason why your documentation isn't being duplicated (i.e. doxygen thinks `Child` inherits from a different `Parent` class).

You might try to force this behavior by using the [\copydoc](http://www.doxygen.nl/manual/commands.html#cmdcopydoc) command. If that still doesn't work you might have to either ask for a patch or fix it yourself.

Comment: Thank you. Do you know how to make it at least document the template Parent? I can't seem to get it to recognize the documentation in the parent.

Comment: It seems you've already solved. Doxygen has the parsing wrong when some previous tag/parsing operation went wrong

Answer (score 1):

I've had a similar problem generating docs of an abstract class. The solution was to make the methods public (by default in a C++ class all methods are private and you need to set EXTRACT_PRIVATE to YES in your Doxygen config file for docs be generated).

I hope this helps someone!